# Internal compiler error with Boost.Spirit

Tags: gcc, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, gcc3, boost-spirit-lex

I'm trying to compile the following seemingly simple code using GCC 3.4.6 and Boost 1.43 and it's generating an internal compiler error:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace lex    = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace qi     = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef lex::lexertl::token<std::string::iterator> TokenT;
typedef lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<TokenT> LexerT;

template <typename LexerT>
struct Tokens: public lex::lexer<LexerT>
{};

int main()
{
   typedef Tokens<LexerT>::iterator_type IteratorT;
   qi::rule<IteratorT, int> expression;

   expression = (qi::int_ >> qi::int_) [ qi::_val = qi::_1 ];
}
```

The generated error:

```
.../boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc/template_arity.hpp:83: internal compiler error: in lookup_member, at cp/search.c:1300
```

The last line in `main()` is generating this error. This error goes away by either letting the `expression` rule work on an `std::string::iterator` instead of `IteratorT`.

Any help with fixing the error while still working with a lexer is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: first off... get a newer compiler. Is this cygwin? Use mingw, link: http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/ (4.7.1 in [64bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/release/) and [32bit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/rubenvb/release/) here)

Comment: Current [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is 4.7.1.  Version 3.4.6 is very, very old (circa March 2006).

Comment: I know it's an old compiler, but that's the latest one supported by the build environment at my work place, so I have no choice! BTW: I made some edits to the question. It seems it has nothing to do with deferred function objects. It's the lexer!

Comment: What build environment only supports GCC 3.4.6? No actual *build* environment I know of.

Comment: It's not really about the build environment I guess (which is internally-built in our case). It's more about the platforms we support (RHEL 3 & 4) and the default compiler and C libraries available on them. Life isn't ideal when it comes to business you know :)

Comment: @HaithamGad as I've argued [more in-depth on the \[spirit-general\] list](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Internal-compiler-error-with-Boost-1-43-and-GCC-3-4-6-tp4633170p4633239.html), I think in this sad case you'd have to accept that Boost Spirit is simply not supported on your platforms. Don't use it. That's business reality for you in my opinion...

Answer (score 1):

You missed the parens:

```
qi::rule<IteratorT, int()> expression;
```

This might fix the compile error (allthough I can't check, since both gcc, clang and msvc happily compiled it)

---

You may want to reduce the compiler stress:

- increase available RAM
- decrease limits (see below)
- disable debug information (-g0)
- and optimizations (-O0; alternatively, optimize for size -Os)

Possibly more in that region.

#### LIMITS

I did a simple

```
grep -EoRh '\<\w+_LIMIT\>' ~/custom/boost_1_50_0/boost/spirit/home/ -h | sort -u
```

to get a list of possible defines, and based a following change on it:

```
#ifdef LEAN
#define PHOENIX_ACTOR_LIMIT      3 // boost 1_50 default: 10
#define PHOENIX_ARG_LIMIT        5 // boost 1_50 default: 10
#define PHOENIX_CATCH_LIMIT      1 // boost 1_50 default:  9
#define PHOENIX_COMPOSITE_LIMIT  5 // boost 1_50 default: 10
#define PHOENIX_DYNAMIC_LIMIT    1 // boost 1_50 default: 10
#define PHOENIX_LIMIT            5 // boost 1_50 default: 10
#define PHOENIX_LOCAL_LIMIT      3 // boost 1_50 default: 10
#define PHOENIX_MEMBER_LIMIT     3 // boost 1_50 default:  8
#define SPIRIT_ARGUMENTS_LIMIT   5 // boost 1_50 default: 10
#define SPIRIT_ATTRIBUTES_LIMIT  5 // boost 1_50 default: 10
#endif

#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_function.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace lex    = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace qi     = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx    = boost::phoenix;

struct funcImpl
{
   template <typename T>
   struct result { typedef int type; };

   template <typename T>
   int operator()(T& x) const {
      return 0;
   }
};

typedef lex::lexertl::token<std::string::iterator> TokenT;
typedef lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<TokenT> LexerT;

template <typename LexerT>
struct Tokens: public lex::lexer<LexerT>
{};

int main()
{
   //typedef Tokens<LexerT>::iterator_type IteratorT;
   typedef char* IteratorT;
   qi::rule<IteratorT, int()> expression;

   phx::function<funcImpl> func = funcImpl();
   expression = (qi::int_ >> qi::int_) [ qi::_val = func(qi::_1) ];


   std::cout   << "#define PHOENIX_ACTOR_LIMIT "                       << PHOENIX_ACTOR_LIMIT                       << '\n';
   std::cout   << "#define PHOENIX_ARG_LIMIT "                         << PHOENIX_ARG_LIMIT                         << '\n';
   std::cout   << "#define PHOENIX_CATCH_LIMIT "                       << PHOENIX_CATCH_LIMIT                       << '\n';
   std::cout   << "#define PHOENIX_COMPOSITE_LIMIT "                   << PHOENIX_COMPOSITE_LIMIT                   << '\n';
   std::cout   << "#define PHOENIX_DYNAMIC_LIMIT "                     << PHOENIX_DYNAMIC_LIMIT                     << '\n';
   std::cout   << "#define PHOENIX_LIMIT "                             << PHOENIX_LIMIT                             << '\n';
   std::cout   << "#define PHOENIX_LOCAL_LIMIT "                       << PHOENIX_LOCAL_LIMIT                       << '\n';
   std::cout   << "#define PHOENIX_MEMBER_LIMIT "                      << PHOENIX_MEMBER_LIMIT                      << '\n';
   std::cout   << "#define SPIRIT_ARGUMENTS_LIMIT "                    << SPIRIT_ARGUMENTS_LIMIT                    << '\n';
   std::cout   << "#define SPIRIT_ATTRIBUTES_LIMIT "                   << SPIRIT_ATTRIBUTES_LIMIT                   << '\n';
   //std::cout << "#define BOOST_PHOENIX_LIMIT "                       << BOOST_PHOENIX_LIMIT                       << '\n';
   //std::cout << "#define BOOST_SPIRIT_CLOSURE_LIMIT "                << BOOST_SPIRIT_CLOSURE_LIMIT                << '\n';
   //std::cout << "#define BOOST_SPIRIT_GRAMMAR_STARTRULE_TYPE_LIMIT " << BOOST_SPIRIT_GRAMMAR_STARTRULE_TYPE_LIMIT << '\n';
   //std::cout << "#define BOOST_SPIRIT_RULE_SCANNERTYPE_LIMIT "       << BOOST_SPIRIT_RULE_SCANNERTYPE_LIMIT       << '\n';
   //std::cout << "#define BOOST_SPIRIT_SELECT_LIMIT "                 << BOOST_SPIRIT_SELECT_LIMIT                 << '\n';
   //std::cout << "#define BOOST_SPIRIT_SWITCH_CASE_LIMIT "            << BOOST_SPIRIT_SWITCH_CASE_LIMIT            << '\n';
   //std::cout << "#define PHOENIX_CONSTRUCT_LIMIT "                   << PHOENIX_CONSTRUCT_LIMIT                   << '\n';
   //std::cout << "#define SPIRIT_CLOSURE_LIMIT "                      << SPIRIT_CLOSURE_LIMIT                      << '\n';
}
```

Now, the following size changes happen (in LoC preprocessed):

```
sehe@mint12:/tmp$ g++ -g0 -O0 -I /home/sehe/custom/boost_1_50_0/ test.cpp -E | wc -l
193011
sehe@mint12:/tmp$ g++ -g0 -O0 -I ./boost_1_43_0/ test.cpp -DLEAN -E | wc -l
168862
```

basically, a >10% reduction in code lines. It just might help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn't fix it!

Comment: @HaithamGad I added some more hints/tweaks that _might_ help you get this past the compiler. I still think you should use a newer compiler. There is no platform where GNU 3.4 is supported anymore anyway. It's rarely hard to extract a tarball in a local directory and just use the binaries from there. IME, this usually works from embedded systems to AIX, Solaris etc.: http://gcc.gnu.org/install/binaries.html

Comment: Thanks Seth. I use a newer compiler at home, and I had my code compiling on it, but when I try the version at my workplace it keeps breaking. The thing is, we release our products on RedHat Enterprise Linux 3 & 4 and this is the default compiler version on these ancient platforms. I tried you're code, but it's still breaking. Anyway, never mind. I think it has to do with a combination of the usage of the lexer, the sequencing operator and the use of semantic actions. I'll try tweaking the code until it compiles.

Comment: I pasted all the errors here in case anyone can decipher any of them:

http://pastebin.com/BMPCSUzc